# Microsoft Access can't append all the records in the append query due to a type conversion failure

Tags: sql, ms-access

Why am I getting a type conversion error?

Here is the insert query:

```
INSERT INTO Products(BarcodeID, ProductColor, ProductSize, ProductName)
VALUES (23749827548, 'Turquoise', 'XS', 'Sun T-shirt')
```

Here is the query where I created the Products table:

```
CREATE TABLE Products
(
BarcodeID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
ProductColor varchar(20),
ProductSize varchar(20),
ProductName varchar(20)
);
```

I tried inserting the BarcodeID with and without single quotation marks to no avail.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: You are using INT as your ID but your value exceeds int size, try changing to BIGINT:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thank you!! @Brad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted from my comments above with code for table:

You are using INT as your ID but your value exceeds INT size, try changing to BIGINT

Link to SQL INT datatypes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

```
CREATE TABLE Products
(
BarcodeID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
ProductColor varchar(20),
ProductSize varchar(20),
ProductName varchar(20)
);
```